# custom input type file, and replace the input type with selected image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```css
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
.upload-icon{
 width: 100px;
 height: 97px;
 border: 2px solid #5642BE;
 border-style: dotted;
 border-radius: 18px;
}
.upload-icon img{
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin:19px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <div class="image-upload">
         <label for="file-input">
           <div class="upload-icon">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            </div>
          </label>
       <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
      </div>
 </form>
```

I want to upload only image with input type file, when an image will be selected for upload then, upload image icon will replace within the selected image(like bellow screenshot). I did not write any script. what should be the script?
[image]

Comment: You should specify your backend language/technology (php? c#? ...)

Comment: *"what should be the script"* ... that really isn't how this site works. It's not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. There are lots of resources on the web on how to accomplish this though. When you have real code and it's not working as expected you will get plenty of help here

Comment: @Verthosa my backend language/technology is php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try use jQuery for this. I made an example below.

The code to make the preview is this:

```
function readURL(input) {
  var id = $(input).attr("id");

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .upload-icon').css("border", "none");
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .icon').hide();
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .prev').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("input[id^='file-input']").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

I've made it more dynamic so you can use the input field multiple times, as in your example image.

Hope it helps you.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  var id = $(input).attr("id");

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .upload-icon').css("border", "none");
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .icon').hide();
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .prev').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("input[id^='file-input']").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.image-upload>input {
  display: none;
}

.upload-icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 97px;
  border: 2px solid #5642BE;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-radius: 18px;
  float: left;
}

.upload-icon .icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  display: none;
  width: 95px;
  height: 92px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
           <div class="upload-icon">
            <img class="icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            <img class="prev" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            </div>
          </label>
    <input id="file-input" type="file" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input2">
           <div class="upload-icon">
            <img class="icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            <img class="prev" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            </div>
          </label>
    <input id="file-input2" type="file" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input3">
           <div class="upload-icon">
            <img class="icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            <img class="prev" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
            </div>
          </label>
    <input id="file-input3" type="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much @Carsten Løvbo Andersen. Is it possible to hide the dotted border after upload an image?

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan Try take a look now

Answer (score 2):

There is a simplest way for this using one line of code. You can create this using `URL.createObjectURL()`, check working snippet for this

```js
$('#file-input').change( function(event) {
    $("img.icon").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    $("img.icon").parents('.upload-icon').addClass('has-img');
});
```

```css
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
.upload-icon{
  width: 100px;
  height: 97px;
  border: 2px solid #5642BE;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
.upload-icon img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin:19px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.upload-icon.has-img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 97px;
    border: none;
}
.upload-icon.has-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <div class="image-upload">
   <label for="file-input">
     <div class="upload-icon">
   <img class="icon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
   </div>
    </label>
    <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the dotted border after upload an image?

Comment: This should be the preferred way since `URL.createObjectURL(userFile)` will only create a direct pointer to the file, whereas FileReader.readAsDataURL will load the file thrice in the memory + always be present in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show preview of your selected image.

```js
        $("#file-input").change(function () {
            readURL(this, 'sampleImageId');
            $('.upload-icon').css('border-style','none');
        });
        
        function readURL(input, id) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#' + id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        }
      }
```

```css
.image-upload > input
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .upload-icon{
     width: 100px;
     height: 97px;
     border: 2px solid #5642BE;
     border-style: dotted;
     border-radius: 18px;
    }
    .upload-icon img{
     width: 90px;
     height: 87px;
     margin:5px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
          <div class="image-upload">
             <label for="file-input">
               <div class="upload-icon">
                <img id="sampleImageId" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/61/61112.png">
                </div>
              </label>
           <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
          </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to hide the dotted border after upload an image?(I am using php language as backend) @Ataur Rahman Munna